# In Android any app can steal focus without requiring any permission

Tags: android, security, usability, foreground

In Android any app can register a BroadcastReceiver and start a new activity using the startActivity method and no permission is required to do that.

I thought that, in the programming world, there was a general consensus about the fact that stealing focus is one of the worst thing a programmer can do, for obvious usability and security reasons.

So my question is why Android allows any app to start a new activity bringing it in the foreground potentially stealing focus to the app the user is using in that moment without requiring ANY permission.

Thanks for every clarification.

Best regards